Is it possible to install Python in a different directory from the node.js default for extra tools and keep using it in node?
I installed node but my ssd only has 6 GB free so I didn't install nose.js extra tools (or something similar) that include python. Yet, once working in node, I realized that at least Python would be very useful specially with some libraries and nodes like robotjs.
My question is: considering I have another SSD with plenty of free space and an external disk, may I install those tools on another drive and keep accessing them by providing a path to node ?

Why not just try it?
